# titanium alloy Widget not working

Tags: titanium, titanium-alloy

The widget that I have is working on other xml files..except for one...
The process goes like this...There's a view that when clicked, a window will open..

```
<Alloy>
  <View class="vertical hsize">
    <View class="hsize">
      <Require src="actionbar" type="widget" />
    </View>
    <ScrollView class="container vertical whitebg">
      <View class="downloadRowContainer horizontal">
        <View class="downloadRow horizontal">
          <View id="itemDl" onClick="viewItem" class="downloadItem graybg" />
          <View class="divider" />
          <View class="downloadItem graybg" />
        </View>
      </View>
      <View class="downloadRowContainer horizontal">
        <View class="downloadRow horizontal">
          <View class="downloadItem graybg" />
          <View class="divider" />
          <View class="downloadItem graybg" />
        </View>
      </View>
    </ScrollView>
  </View>
</Alloy>
```

Here's the js:

```
function viewItem(e){
  var showItem = Alloy.createController('viewdl').getView().open();
}
```

It works it opens viewdl.xml but the widget ain't working anymore on viewdl.xml alone.Any idea why?
Here's viewdl.xml(viewdl.js is blank):

```
<Alloy><Window class="vertical">
<View class="vertical hsize">
  <View class="hsize"><Require src="actionbar" type="widget"/></View>
    <ScrollView class="container vertical blackbg">
      <View class="imgContainer"></View>
        <View class="division"></View>
          <Label>DOWNLOAD THIS WALLPAPER</Label>
    </ScrollView>
</View></Window></Alloy>
```

Comment: Can you show code of `viewdl.xml` and `viewdl.js`. Also what error do you get in console.

Comment: theres no error..it works but not the widget wait ill post viewdl.xml

Comment: I think you have not pasted complete code of `viewdl.xml` code. Also can you provide link/info of your `actionbar` widget. A quick try could be use `var showItem = Alloy.createController('viewdl').getView().open({fullscreen:false});`

Comment: sorry about that..one quick question...how do you open an .xml file  without <Window></Window> tags..cause the other .xml files with the widget are working fine..and is alloy.createcontroller only for opening windows...very new to titanium sorry

Comment: You cannot open an xml file without `window` because `open` method is not available for `view`. You can export the content of the xml and add it to current `window` or `view` like `$.myCurrentView.add(Alloy.createController('viewdl').getView());`

Comment: oh okay thanks a lot turtle...the first xml that I have on the post...how should I close it?..I did $.downloads.close(); there was  an error...

Answer (score 0):

Let me elaborate some points which I think are creating issues:

- The root of the UI is [Window](http://docs.appcelerator.com/titanium/latest/#!/api/Titanium.UI.Window) or [TabGroup](http://docs.appcelerator.com/titanium/latest/#!/api/Titanium.UI.TabGroup) or [NavigationWindow](http://docs.appcelerator.com/titanium/latest/#!/api/Titanium.UI.iOS.NavigationWindow)/[NavigationGroup](http://docs.appcelerator.com/titanium/latest/#!/api/Titanium.UI.MobileWeb.NavigationGroup) : So these elements are responsible for opening and closing of the content/container in screen.
- You can add some other [View](http://docs.appcelerator.com/titanium/latest/#!/api/Titanium.UI.View) or its sub-element(Label,TableView,etc) to a window using `add` method.
- IMO the widget should be added to the main container.

---

*A simple example*, let say we want 2 window application.

- 1st Window has a button which opens 2nd window.
- 2nd Window has 2 buttons

  1. 1st button close the current window.
  2. 2nd button loads some other view ( xml file ) to current window.

**index.xml**

```
<Alloy>
  <Window id="first" layout="vertical" >
     <Require src="actionbar" type="widget" />
     <Button onClick="openWin2" title="Open" />
  </Window>
</Alloy>
```

**index.js**

```
function openWin2() {
  Alloy.createController('window2').getView().open({fullscreen:false});
}
```

**window2.xml**

```
<Alloy>
  <Window id="second" layout="vertical" >
     <Require src="actionbar" type="widget" />
     <Button onClick="closeWin" title="Close" />
     <Button onClick="loadData" title="Load Data" />
     <View id="dynamicView" height="100px" width="100px"></View>
  </Window>
</Alloy>
```

**window2.js**

```
function closeWin() {
  $.second.close();
}

function loadData() {
  $.dynamicView.add(Alloy.createController('dynamicData').getView());
}
```

**dynamicData.xml**

```
<Alloy>
  <Label >Winter is coming !!</Label>
</Alloy>
```

*Hope it is helpful.*